# Device/Browser Details when running Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

There is a package/plugin for Flutter Mobile (Android, iOS) for retrieving the device details, in which the the flutter application is running, [device_info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info). What i need is a package/plugin to get the Details of the Device/Browser in which the Flutter Web application is running. If anyone can steer me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: what kind of information you want from the device?

Comment: Some basic information like the current browser, browser version, OS, Os Version, other basic details to identify Client in which the flutter is running

Comment: Hi, @JemsheerKDc  I have the same case like your question, did you find any solution for your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get current device information from within the Flutter application, and it works for WEB as well as desktop apps
[device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus)

you can get following details of a browser
`'browserName': describeEnum(data.browserName),`

More details are there in this example https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/device_info_plus/example/lib/main.dart#L138

Answer (score 1):

Use this library `device_info_plus: ^9.0.2`

```
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

final deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
final deviceInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.deviceInfo;
final allInfo = deviceInfo.data;
print(allInfo.toString());
```

> Chrome Output

```
{
  browserName: BrowserName.chrome,
  appCodeName: Mozilla,
  appName: Netscape,
  appVersion: 5.0(WindowsNT10.0;Win64;x64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,
  likeGecko)Chrome/114.0.0.0Safari/537.36,
  deviceMemory: 8,
  language: en-US,
  languages: [
    en-US
  ],
  platform: Win32,
  product: Gecko,
  productSub: 20030107,
  userAgent: Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT10.0;Win64;x64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,
  likeGecko)Chrome/114.0.0.0Safari/537.36,
  vendor: GoogleInc.,
  vendorSub: ,
  hardwareConcurrency: 4,
  maxTouchPoints: 0
}
```

> Firefox Output

```
{
  browserName: BrowserName.firefox,
  appCodeName: Mozilla,
  appName: Netscape,
  appVersion: 5.0(Windows),
  deviceMemory: null,
  language: en-US,
  languages: [
    en-US,
    en
  ],
  platform: Win32,
  product: Gecko,
  productSub: 20100101,
  userAgent: Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT10.0;Win64;x64;rv: 109.0)Gecko/20100101Firefox/114.0,
  vendor: ,
  vendorSub: ,
  hardwareConcurrency: 4,
  maxTouchPoints: 0
}
```

> Microsoft Edge Output

```
{
  browserName: BrowserName.edge,
  appCodeName: Mozilla,
  appName: Netscape,
  appVersion: 5.0(WindowsNT10.0;Win64;x64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,
  likeGecko)Chrome/114.0.0.0Safari/537.36Edg/114.0.1823.58,
  deviceMemory: 8,
  language: en-US,
  languages: [
    en-US
  ],
  platform: Win32,
  product: Gecko,
  productSub: 20030107,
  userAgent: Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT10.0;Win64;x64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,
  likeGecko)Chrome/114.0.0.0Safari/537.36Edg/114.0.1823.58,
  vendor: GoogleInc.,
  vendorSub: ,
  hardwareConcurrency: 4,
  maxTouchPoints: 0
}
```